# Why rules for travelling to England say "you cannot use the EU DCC to add proof of vaccination" for a few EU countries?

Tags: uk, covid-19, eu, england

I want to travel to England from an EU country and I am fully vaccinated. I have the EU DCC QR code. However, I'm reading about "Approved proof of vaccination" in [this](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/countries-with-approved-covid-19-vaccination-programmes-and-proof-of-vaccination#proof-of-vaccination) gov.uk page and for a number of EU countries

> Andorra, Bulgaria, Czech Republic (Czechia), Germany, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Monaco, San  Marino and Ukraine
>
> Last updated 8 November 2021

it says:

**EU DCC – you cannot use the EU DCC to add proof of vaccination status in the UK passenger locator form.**

For these countries, it doesn't list "Vaccine certificate." as a proof either.

If I come from one of these countries, does it mean England doesn't consider my certificate valid? Should I follow rules for non-vaccinated people?

Comment: 6 countries were added yesterday, at [2021-11-11 05:31:18: only Andorra, Monaco and San Marino were listed.](https://web.archive.org/web/20211111053118/https://www.gov.uk/guidance/countries-with-approved-covid-19-vaccination-programmes-and-proof-of-vaccination)

Comment: Some of those countries (Andorra, Liechtenstein, Monaco, San Marino and Ukraine) are actually not EU countries, which lay explain things. But it’s more likely it means the UK does not (yet?) have the public keys for the countries listed, which prevents them from verifying the certificates they issue. There were similar issues for Switzerland at some point IIRC.

Comment: I think @jcaron is correct but can’t find an official source for now. I’ve emailed the gov.uk support team to ask, the exclusion that makes least sense to me on the assumption of not yet being able to verify the certificates is Germany.

Comment: Just a speculation, but UK authorities may even consider the risk of fake certificates from these countries and therefore not accept them. At least here in Germany, it is not very difficult to obtain a seemingly genuine DCC without being vaccinated.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo “seemingly genuine”? Does it pass verification via the official apps (I.e. is it properly signed)?

Comment: @jcaron No, it is a reference to the rising attempts to get a valid EU DCC using counterfeited (paper based) certificates.

Comment: @jcaron Yes, the DCC itself is properly issued and valid, it is simply too easy to fake the requirements for obtaining a digital certificate. You can go to almost any pharmacy in Germany with an old-style WHO standard ICVP (handwritten paper booklet, 'Yellow Card'), which is easily forged, and get a digital certificate issued. The pharmasists are not educated to recognize forged ICVPs. There are also doctors in Germany selling properly issued ICVPs without actually administrating the vaccine. And yes, I have first hand experience with both types of fraud.

Comment: @Traveller I was unable to find a support email for the gov.uk Can you tell me that email please? I did however email British embassy in my country to ask about this, but only received a very generic reply saying I should read everything on the gov.uk (which I've already done and didn't find anything for the countries in question)

Comment: @Boring person I got a similar generic reply, saying the support team can’t answer questions about content/policy, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table's heading says "Examples of proof of vaccination status and whether you can verify this on the UK passenger locator form".

EU DCC is an example of the proof of vaccination status for e.g. Germany. It is just that you cannot verify the EU DCC issued by Germany with the passenger locator form; just like for someone having a vaccination proof issued by Canada, they can nonetheless be treated as vaccinated for entry into UK.

On the [passenger locator form](https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk), it says

> **Proving your vaccination status**
>
> You can use this service to prove your vaccination status if you have:
>
> - your NHS COVID Pass
> - your NHS Scotland vaccination status
> - your NI COVID certificate
> - your EU Digital COVID certificate - check if your EU Digital COVID certificate is eligible and if your vaccine is accepted
>
> If you choose to do this, you’ll need to provide a scan or screenshot
> of the QR code from your valid vaccination certificate.
>
> You may still be asked to show your vaccination certificate to prove
> your vaccination status when you travel.
>
> ***If you cannot use this service, or you choose not to, you must use
> your vaccination certificate to prove your vaccination status before
> you board your plane, train or ferry to the UK.***

Comment: I still find it somewhat unclear. So for example, an EU DCC generated in Bulgaria or Germany can be used to prove a vaccination status, but just cannot be verified in the form?

Comment: @CrispyHoliday yes. It will be verified when you travel.

Answer (score 4):

From today (2021-11-16), the message has been updated:

You can use the EU DCC to prove your vaccination status. You cannot currently use your EU DCC to verify your vaccination status via the UK passenger locator form.